# Celery missing backend result

Tags: python, redis, celery

I tried using Celery for some I/O tasks for my project, but I reached a dead end and I would really appreciate your help with this if possible.

So what I'm trying to achieve basically is to first run a group of the same task on multiple remote machines (e.g. copying some files on them) and after that run another group of the another task type (e.g. installing a Python module on the machines).

I've tried implementing this stuff like this:

```
final_job = chain( group(copy_files_job) | HandleResults().s(), group(install_module_job) | HandleResults().s())
```

`result = final_job.delay()`

What I would like to achieve with this is to also report for each group of tasks the result back to a web interface. I'm not entirely sure if this is the correct way of doing what I want with Celery.

But running this will return a `NotImplementedError: Starting chords requires a result backend to be configured.` This is not true though, because I use Redis both as broker and result backend and it works well if I don't add the second group of tasks with the handle results task (`group(install_module_job) | HandleResults().s())`).

So it's clear that the error is not the correct one. I guess Celery tries to tell me that I configured the final_job the wrong way, but I really don't know how else can I write what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Keep in mind that this is happening on the client (Producer) side. So if you did not configure your Celery app properly (result backend), you would see such an error. Your Celery workers are probably configured well, but the script that runs `final_job.delay()` should have configured Celery with the result_backend too.